# Using an ObjectDataSource to Update a GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sql-update, objectdatasource

I currently am working on a project that is using ObjectDataSources along with a GridView control to run some database access and updating.

The current issue I am running into is that when clicking the Update button within the gridview an exception error is thrown out. From what I understand this error seems to be saying that the grid-view is passing to many parameters to the update statement.

I would like it to send 2 objects, "orignal_Incident" and "incident", which should hold all the fields that I need. But it seems it is also passing along the fields "DateClosed" and "Description".

Is there possibly a way to edit which parameters the gridview sends? Or is there something else that needs to be done to make this work?

Below is the code and errors pertaining to this portion of the program:

Error:

> ObjectDataSource 'obsIncidents' could not find a non-generic method 'UpdateIncident' that has parameters: original_Incident, incident, DateClosed, Description.

ASP.NET code for ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="obsIncidents" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetCustomerIncidents" TypeName="IncidentDB" UpdateMethod="UpdateIncident">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCustomer" Name="CustomerID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Incident" Type="Object" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="incident" Type="Object" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

ASP.NET code for GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvIncidents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="obsIncidents" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IncidentID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" ControlStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductCode" HeaderText="Product Code" ReadOnly="True" ControlStyle-Width="70" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOpened" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Date Opened" ReadOnly="True" ControlStyle-Width="70" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateClosed" HeaderText="Date Closed" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ControlStyle-Width="70" ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True" ControlStyle-Width="150" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ControlStyle-Width="300" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' Width="300"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' Width="300" Rows="4" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Visual Basic update method in class-file

```
<DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)>
Public Shared Function UpdateIncident(
        ByVal original_Incident As Incident,
        ByVal incident As Incident) As Integer
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(TechSupportDB.GetConnectionString)
    Dim up As String = "UPDATE Incidents " &
                       "SET DateClosed = @DateClosed, " &
                       "Description = @Description " &
                       "WHERE IncidentID = @original_IncidentID " &
                       "AND ProductCode = @original_ProductCode " &
                       "AND DateOpened = @original_DateOpened " &
                       "AND (DateClosed = @original_DateClosed " &
                       "OR DateClosed IS NULL " &
                       "AND @original_DateClosed IS NULL) " &
                       "AND Title = @original_Title " &
                       "AND Description = @original_Description"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(up, con)
    If incident.DateClosed = #12:00:00 AM# Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateClosed", DBNull.Value)
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateClosed", incident.DateClosed)
    End If
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", incident.description)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_IncidentID", original_Incident.IncidentID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_ProductCode", original_Incident.ProductCode)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_DateOpened", original_Incident.DateOpened)
    If original_Incident.DateClosed = #12:00:00 AM# Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_DateClosed", DBNull.Value)
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_DateClosed", original_Incident.DateClosed)
    End If
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_Title", original_Incident.title)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_Description", original_Incident.description)
    con.Open()
    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Return i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

AzureShadow,

Just change OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" to OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}". It should work perfectly! I think your case and [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847942/objectdatasource-update) are quite similar. Have a look at that post as well. It will be quite clear.